# Azure service fabric - install.sh file not found

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to follow the tutorial, but I can not find the [install.sh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers-linux#deploy-the-application) file.

How could I generate the file? or where could I find it if it was created by Microsoft?

Comment: random result from google: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-core-getting-started/blob/master/Services/CounterService/install.sh

Comment: thank you but I think that script is not for the example of the page I posted. I'm sure it could be addapted, but I'm also sure Microsoft has public a particular install.sh for that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers-linux#deploy-the-application) you linked:

> Use the install script provided in the template to copy the application package to the cluster's image store, register the application type, and create an instance of the application.

The Yeoman template should generate in the root folder a bash script called `install.sh` and|or a powershell script called `install.ps1`, if it didn't generate, probably a problem has occurred, in any case you could copy a script from one of the demos:

```
Services/CounterService/install.sh

#!/bin/bash
create_app()
{
  sfctl application create --app-name fabric:/CounterServiceApplication --app-type CounterServiceApplicationType --app-version 1.0.0 --parameters $1
}
print_help()
{
  echo "Additional Options"
  echo "-onebox (Default): If you are deploying application on one box cluster"
  echo "-multinode: If you are deploying application on a multi node cluster"
}

if [ "$1" = "--help" ]
  then
    print_help
    exit 0
fi
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

appPkg="$DIR/CounterServiceApplication"

WebServiceManifestlocation="$appPkg/CounterServiceWebServicePkg"
WebServiceManifestlocationLinux="$WebServiceManifestlocation/ServiceManifest-Linux.xml"
WebServiceManifestlocationWindows="$WebServiceManifestlocation/ServiceManifest-Windows.xml"
WebServiceManifestlocation="$WebServiceManifestlocation/ServiceManifest.xml"
cp $WebServiceManifestlocationLinux $WebServiceManifestlocation 


StatefulServiceManifestlocation="$appPkg/CounterServicePkg"
StatefulServiceManifestlocationLinux="$StatefulServiceManifestlocation/ServiceManifest-Linux.xml"
StatefulServiceManifestlocationWindows="$StatefulServiceManifestlocation/ServiceManifest-Windows.xml"
StatefulServiceManifestlocation="$StatefulServiceManifestlocation/ServiceManifest.xml"
cp $StatefulServiceManifestlocationLinux $StatefulServiceManifestlocation
cp dotnet-include.sh ./CounterServiceApplication/CounterServicePkg/Code
cp dotnet-include.sh ./CounterServiceApplication/CounterServiceWebServicePkg/Code
sfctl application upload --path CounterServiceApplication --show-progress
sfctl application provision --application-type-build-path CounterServiceApplication
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "No arguments supplied, proceed with default instanceCount of 1"
    create_app "{\"CounterServiceWebService_InstanceCount\":\"1\"}"
  elif [ $1 = "-onebox" ]
  then
    echo "Onebox environment, proceed with default instanceCount of 1."
    create_app "{\"CounterServiceWebService_InstanceCount\":\"1\"}"
  elif [ $1 = "-multinode" ]
  then
    echo "Multinode env, proceed with default instanceCount of -1"
    create_app {}
fi
```

Replace the `CounterService` to the name of your app